# Best way to synchronize(one way) a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, ssms

What is the best way to synchronize(one way) a table in SQL Server 
WHEN

- Tables are in different schema but same domain
- Tables are in different schema and different domain
- Tables are in same schema and different domain

Kindly share with an example.

Comment: what do you mean by domain here? You mean Server?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Whales: I created a procedure, which truncates and copies all records. This job is running fine with, 
1. Same schema same Domain
2. Different schema same Domain
But to run it successfully, it is required to have a similar user on both the databases with sysadmin role

Comment: @AbdulMueedShahid: For example, a company may require all local computers to be networked within the same domain so that each computer can be seen from other computers within the domain or located from a central server.